# why i couldn't found Spritebatch class?

Tags: c#, xna

i have been tring to find microsoft.xna.framework that content Spritebatch class to define object form it to pass through AutoInitialize Method but nothing help me though this and this is my class:

```
#region Using Statements
using System;
using DPSF;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
#endregion

namespace Scientifical_Calculations
{
#if (WINDOWS)
[Serializable]
#endif

    class SphereParticle : DefaultTexturedQuadParticle
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The position of the particle on the sphere, independent of the emitter's position.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3 sEmitterIndependentPosition;

        /// <summary>
        /// How fast the particle is rotating around the sphere's origin.
        /// </summary>
        public Vector3 sPivotRotationVelocity;

        public override void Reset()
        {
            base.Reset();
            sEmitterIndependentPosition = Vector3.Zero;
            sPivotRotationVelocity = Vector3.Zero;
        }

        public override void CopyFrom(DPSFParticle ParticleToCopy)
        {

            base.CopyFrom(ParticleToCopy);
            SphereParticle cParticle = (SphereParticle)ParticleToCopy;
            sEmitterIndependentPosition = cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition;
            sPivotRotationVelocity = cParticle.sPivotRotationVelocity;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new Particle System class that inherits from a Default DPSF Particle System.
    /// </summary>
#if (WINDOWS)
[Serializable]
#endif
    class SphereParticleSystem : DPSFDefaultTexturedQuadParticleSystem<SphereParticle, DefaultTexturedQuadParticleVertex>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cGame">Handle to the Game object being used. Pass in null for this 
        /// parameter if not using a Game object.</param>
        public SphereParticleSystem(Game cGame) : base(cGame) { }

        //===========================================================
        // Structures and Variables
        //===========================================================

        int miNumberOfParticles = 100;
        float mfSphereRadius = 50;
        float mfParticlePivotRotationMaxSpeed = MathHelper.PiOver2;
        Vector3 mfParticlePivotRotationDirection = DPSFHelper.RandomNormalizedVector();

        //===========================================================
        // Overridden Particle System Functions
        //===========================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Function to setup the Render Properties (i.e. BlendState, DepthStencilState, RasterizerState, and SamplerState)
        /// which will be applied to the Graphics Device before drawing the Particle System's Particles.
        /// <para>This function is called when initializing the particle system.</para>
        /// </summary>
        protected override void InitializeRenderProperties()
        {
            base.InitializeRenderProperties();
            // Use additive blending
            RenderProperties.BlendState = BlendState.Additive;
        }

        //===========================================================
        // Initialization Functions
        //===========================================================

        /// <summary>
        /// Function to Initialize the Particle System with default values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cGraphicsDevice">The Graphics Device to draw to</param>
        /// <param name="cContentManager">The Content Manager to use to load Textures and Effect files</param>
        public override void AutoInitialize(GraphicsDevice cGraphicsDevice, ContentManager cContentManager, SpriteBatch cSpriteBatch)
        {
            // Initialize the Particle System before doing anything else
            InitializeTexturedQuadParticleSystem(cGraphicsDevice, cContentManager, miNumberOfParticles, miNumberOfParticles,
                                                UpdateVertexProperties, "Textures/Particle");

            // Set the Name of the Particle System
            Name = "Sphere";

            // Finish loading the Particle System in a separate function call, so if
            // we want to reset the Particle System later we don't need to completely 
            // re-initialize it, we can just call this function to reset it.
            LoadParticleSystem();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load the Particle System Events and any other settings
        /// </summary>
        public void LoadParticleSystem()
        {
            ParticleInitializationFunction = InitializeParticleProperties;

            // Remove all Events first so that none are added twice if this function is called again
            ParticleEvents.RemoveAllEvents();
            ParticleSystemEvents.RemoveAllEvents();

            // Allow the Particle's Velocity, Rotational Velocity, Width and Height, Color, Transparency, and Orientation to be updated each frame
            ParticleEvents.AddEveryTimeEvent(UpdateParticlePositionAndVelocityUsingAcceleration);
            ParticleEvents.AddEveryTimeEvent(UpdateParticleRotationUsingRotationalVelocity);
            ParticleEvents.AddEveryTimeEvent(UpdateParticlePositionToRotateAroundEmitter);

            // This function must be executed after the Color Lerp function as the Color Lerp will overwrite the Color's
            // Transparency value, so we give this function an Execution Order of 100 to make sure it is executed last.
            ParticleEvents.AddEveryTimeEvent(UpdateParticleTransparencyToFadeOutUsingLerp, 100);

            ParticleEvents.AddEveryTimeEvent(UpdateParticleToFaceTheCamera, 200);

            // Setup the Emitter
            Emitter.ParticlesPerSecond = 100;
            Emitter.PositionData.Position = new Vector3(0, 60, 0);

            MaxNumberOfParticlesAllowed = miNumberOfParticles;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Example of how to create a Particle Initialization Function
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cParticle">The Particle to be Initialized</param>
        public void InitializeParticleProperties(SphereParticle cParticle)
        {
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            // TODO: Initialize all of the Particle's properties here.
            // If you plan on simply using the default InitializeParticleUsingInitialProperties
            // Particle Initialization Function (see the LoadParticleSystem() function above), 
            // then you may delete this function all together.
            //-----------------------------------------------------------
            cParticle.Lifetime = 0.0f;

            // Set the Particle's initial Position to be wherever the Emitter is
            cParticle.Position = Emitter.PositionData.Position;

            // Set the Particle to be Radius amount away from the Emitter
            cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition.X = mfSphereRadius;

            // Rotate the Particle to start somewhere on the surface of the sphere
            cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition = DPSFHelper.PointOnSphere(DPSFHelper.RandomNumberBetween(0, MathHelper.TwoPi), DPSFHelper.RandomNumberBetween(0, MathHelper.TwoPi), mfSphereRadius);

            cParticle.Size = 20;

            // Give the Particle a random Color
            // Since we have Color Lerp enabled we must also set the Start and End Color
            cParticle.Color = DPSFHelper.RandomColor();

            cParticle.sPivotRotationVelocity = DPSFHelper.RandomNormalizedVector() * mfParticlePivotRotationMaxSpeed * RandomNumber.NextFloat();
        }

        //===========================================================
        // Particle Update Functions
        //===========================================================

        /// <summary>
        /// Rotate a Particle around the Emitter
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cParticle">The Particle to update</param>
        /// <param name="fElapsedTimeInSeconds">How long it has been since the last update</param>
        protected void UpdateParticlePositionToRotateAroundEmitter(SphereParticle cParticle, float fElapsedTimeInSeconds)
        {
            // Calculate how much to rotate this frame and Rotate the Particle's Position
            Vector3 sRotationAmount = cParticle.sPivotRotationVelocity * fElapsedTimeInSeconds;
            Matrix sRotation = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(sRotationAmount.Y, sRotationAmount.X, sRotationAmount.Z);

            // Rotate the particle around the Emitter
            cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition = PivotPoint3D.RotatePosition(sRotation, Vector3.Zero, cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition);
            cParticle.Position = cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition + Emitter.PositionData.Position;
        }

        protected void UpdateParticleDistanceFromEmitter(SphereParticle cParticle, float fElapsedTimeInSeconds)
        {
            Vector3 sDirectionToParticle = cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition;
            sDirectionToParticle.Normalize();
            cParticle.sEmitterIndependentPosition = sDirectionToParticle * mfSphereRadius;
        }

        protected void UpdateParticlePivotRotationVelocityRandomly(SphereParticle cParticle, float fElapsedTimeInSeconds)
        {
            cParticle.sPivotRotationVelocity = DPSFHelper.RandomNormalizedVector() * mfParticlePivotRotationMaxSpeed * RandomNumber.NextFloat();
        }

        protected void UpdateParticlePivotRotationVelocityToBeTheSame(SphereParticle cParticle, float fElapsedTimeInSeconds)
        {
            cParticle.sPivotRotationVelocity = mfParticlePivotRotationDirection * mfParticlePivotRotationMaxSpeed * RandomNumber.NextFloat();
        }

        //===========================================================
        // Particle System Update Functions
        //===========================================================

        //===========================================================
        // Other Particle System Functions
        //===========================================================

        public void ChangeSphereRadius(float fAmountToChange)
        {
            mfSphereRadius += fAmountToChange;
            if (mfSphereRadius < 20)
            {
                mfSphereRadius = 20;
            }
            ParticleEvents.AddOneTimeEvent(UpdateParticleDistanceFromEmitter);
        }

        public void MakeParticlesTravelInTheSameDirection()
        {
            mfParticlePivotRotationDirection = DPSFHelper.RandomNormalizedVector();
            ParticleEvents.AddOneTimeEvent(UpdateParticlePivotRotationVelocityToBeTheSame);
        }

        public void MakeParticlesTravelInRandomDirections()
        {
            ParticleEvents.AddOneTimeEvent(UpdateParticlePivotRotationVelocityRandomly);
        }

        public void ChangeNumberOfParticles(int iAmountToChange)
        {
            MaxNumberOfParticlesAllowed += iAmountToChange;

            if (MaxNumberOfParticlesAllowed < 50)
            {
                MaxNumberOfParticlesAllowed = 50;
            }
            NumberOfParticlesAllocatedInMemory = MaxNumberOfParticlesAllowed;
        }
    }
}
```

i use DPSF library to help me in partical systems my problem her that SpiritBatch  Class Couldn't Found i wonder if any one can help

Comment: did you add it to the project as well by right clicking on `References=>add` and locating the `DPSF` dll...?

Comment: yes i add  The DPSF.dll my problem here in Microsoft.Xna.framework library Spritebatch class suppose to be with it

Comment: what about the other 3rd party .dll's did you add them to the references as well I see them in your using

Comment: Yes nothing Wrong with the references i add them all

Comment: how about trying to create the same thing in a small windows application and see if it works.. I wonder if the way that you are using the partial classes and or copying / loading could be an issue.. also check namespace as well

Comment: Add a reference to **Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics**. Was you project not created with the XNA wizard?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.aspx

Comment: i solved the problem it was that i haven't installed  Xna Game Studio yet so i installed it and it works Thanks Guys I really appreciate it

Comment: That problem though, wanted to program in XNA but forgot to install it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like XNA isn't installed.  Try creating a new XNA project in Visual Studio (not using the DPSF library) - just as a test.  If you are unable to do that then you need to install XNA.  There's a good library for installing XNA here:

http://msxna.codeplex.com/